# How to merge two React hook outputs into one

Tags: reactjs, merge, react-hooks, compare

I have two hooks and I want the output of that hook should be compared to each other means in 1 hook there are maybe id 1 and id 2 which has some purchase value and in 2nd hook, there is an id that may contain both id 1 and 2 or contains only one which has different purchase value for maybe last year so I want to compare these two hooks and output of this hook I want to save it in 1 another hook so that I can show that output in table structure.

**```useEffect(()=>{
Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/date/${purchase_date}`).then((response)=>{
console.log(response.data)
setlistOfDate(response.data)

})})
useEffect(()=>{
axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/date/stk/${purchase_date}`).then((response)=>{
console.log(response.data)
setlastDateStk(response.data)
})})```**

> > 

I want to compare this two output and shows the results in the Html Table structure
I tried two options that I found in StackOverflow treads which is
1.

````
 Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/date/${purchase_date}`)
 .then(res=>{
   setlistOfDate(res.data)
   setIsLoading(false)
 })
 .catch(err=>{
   console.log(err)
 });
 axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/date/stk/${purchase_date}`)
 .then(res=>{
   setlastDateStk(res.data.results)
   setIsLoading(false)
 })
 .catch(err=>{
   console.log(err)
 });
},[]);
useEffect(()=>{
 setTest({...test,listOfDate,lastDateStk})
},[listOfDate,lastDateStk])```**
>>
here error is coming that I cannot use parameter {purchase_date}
and 

2.


**```useEffect(()=>{
 setIsLoading(true);
 Promise.all([
   Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/stk/${purchase_date}`),
   Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/${purchase_date}`)
 ]).then((results)=>{
  setIsLoading(false);
  setTest({
   listOfDate:results[0].data,
   lastDateStk:results[1].data.results
  });
 }).catch((err)=>{
   setIsLoading(false)
   console.log(err)
 });
},[])```**

>>
I don't know how can I do it.
Please help I am stuck on this problem for the last 2 days, tried everything but I guess because of my lack of knowledge about hooks merging it's not working, I must be missing something 
Thank you in advance
````

Comment: you can acces to `purchase_date` out of the useEffect? what hooks you want to merge?

Comment: actually, purchase_date is helping me to get the data from the database based on that particular date so I guess that purchase_date should be there in the axios.get() , const [listOfDate,setlistOfDate]= useState([])
const [lastDateStk,setlastDateStk] = useState([])   these are the two hooks which have a output that I want to compare and print in table

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why can't access to `purchase_date` but you can make in other way

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 const getData = async ()=>{
  try {
   setIsLoading(true);
   const res1 = await Axios
     .get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/stk/${purchase_date}`)
   const res2 = await Axios
     .get(`http://localhost:3001/inoutTo/report/${purchase_date}`)
   setIsLoading(false);
  // here you can set individualy or if you have an state like an object with 2 values
  setTest({
     listOfDate:res1.data,
     lastDateStk:res2.data.results
    });
  } catch (error) {
   setIsLoading(false);
   // manage the error
  }
 }

getData()
,[])
```

Dont forget to check how is the structure of the response

Comment: Hello sir, i tried your version of code but still there is a warning "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'purchase_date'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" but individually this two links are working I checked in a postman app but while combining this hook warning is coming and no data is coming